# How to get rid of some spacing when website switches to mobile view

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a landing page where people would click on which website they want to go to. I'm new to coding and need some help with the mobile version of the website. There is some spacing that I want to get rid of but I'm not sure how to go about this.

Seen here, I'm trying to get rid of the spacing in between the image blocks on the mobile version. [Mobile version of site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cBWk.png)

Thanks!

CSS

```
 body {
      width:100%;
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
    }

    .flex {
   display:flex;
   max-width: 80%;
    }
    .flex div{
      flex:1;
      padding:20px;
    }

    img{
      margin:30% auto 30%;
      width:100%;

@media only screen and (max-width:620px) {
  .flex, .flex div, img {
    display:inline;
    width:100%;
    float:left;
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<body>
  <div class="flex">
    <div>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/926x1104" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/926x1104" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/926x1104" />
    </div>

  </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please create a working js fiddle example for us to see visually. Also get rid of all those -moz and -webkit prefixes, they are hurting our eyes and you don't need them anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should provide us more info. But to get rid of all the spacing you could try this for mobile:

```
@media only screen and (max-width:620px) {
  .flex, .flex div, img {
    display:inline;
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
```

Comment: Sorry I was having a hard time trying to explain what I was trying to do. .But your code seemed to have fixed the spacing! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A few things needed to change:

1. kill the float that you have in the media query. You're using flex, so
2. Add the reset to both html and body.
3. In the media query use justify-content and flex-direction. Set the max-width to 100%

the TL:DR of what was wrong was that you we're floating elements on a media query, and giving them a width of less than 100% which is why they were not centered on mobile.

```css
    html, body {
      width:100%;
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    .flex {
   display:flex;
   max-width: 80%;
    }
    .flex div{
      flex:1;
      padding:20px;
    }
    img{
      margin:30% auto 30%;
      width:100%;
      -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
      transition: all 0.3s;
    }
    img:hover {
      -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
      -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
      transform: scale(1.1);
    }

@media only screen and (max-width:620px) {
  .flex {
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    max-width:100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="flex">
    <div>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/926x1104" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/926x1104" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/926x1104" />
    </div>

  </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps.